# Date compare with user input date and date from file

Tags: c

I need some help in doing a comparison of dates. The program works when the user enters the input date and it will compare it with a text document file on its date. If the dates is between the user enter date and it matches the document date then it will be executed.. Im thinking of using a switch case for this case instead of if.. is it possible?

```
if (date_compare(tld->begin, d) > 0 && //compare user input start date with actual date.txt begin input date
        date_compare(tld->end, d) < 0) //compare user input end date with actual date.txt input date
    return 0;
```

Comment: Yes it's possible. There are also tons of date-comparison functions if you just search a little.

Comment: What do you mean by "case diagram"? Switch / case statements?

Comment: Yes switch case my bad.. How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using some library for date arithmetic and comparison. It can be very tricky to properly code it for a serious production code, especially with locales. Starting with leap years, through leap seconds, into pearls like one of the top questions [Why is subtracting these two times (in 1927) giving a strange result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result).

For simple starters I would recommend using standard library [difftime](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/difftime) from [chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono) utilities.

The `if` you showed seems fine for me, and you can easily wrap `difftime` with `date_compare`.

Two concerns though.

What is the order of operands for your date_compare? For `difftime` the signature is `double difftime( time_t time_end, time_t time_beg );`, which would seem to be opposite to what you use. Otherwise the statement would logically be always false.

Also you seem to check whether `d` is inside `(tld->start; tld->begin)` and if so you exit with `0`. In other words, you return `0` when the file fits into the date interval, I hope this is intended.